# Prove that rank(F)=height for logical formula

Tags: logic

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$The function rank is defined as:

1. $\rank(p) = 1$
2. $\rank(\lnot\Phi) = 1+\rank(\Phi)$
3. $\rank(\Phi\circ\Psi) =1+\max(\rank(\Phi),\rank(\Psi))$

Where $\circ$ is a binary logical operator.

and the heightis defined as the longest path from the root node to the leaf. Now i have to prove that $\rank(\Phi)$ returns the height of a logical formula.

IH: $\rank(\Phi)$ returns the height of a logical formula for $height=n$

BC1: $\rank(p)=1$ and $p$ has $\operatorname{height}=1$$

BC2:$\rank(\lnot p)=1+\rank(p)=1+1=2$ and $\lnot p$ has $\operatorname{height}=2$

BC3:$\rank(p\circ q)=1+\max(\rank(p),\rank(q))=1+1=2$ and $p\circ q$ has height 2

Now the Steps:   $\operatorname{height}=n+1$

SC1: $\rank(\lnot \Phi)=1+\rank(\Phi)$ now i know that $\rank(\Phi)$ has $\operatorname{height}=n$  (IH) and I am done here because $\rank(\lnot\Phi)=1+\rank(\Phi)=1+n=\operatorname{height}(\Phi)$

SC2: $\rank(\Phi\circ\Phi)=1+\max(\rank(\Phi),\rank(\Phi))=1+n=\operatorname{height}(\Phi)$

Now my question: I think that the step cases (especially the 2nd on) might be wrong. Is my prove right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your induction hypothesis could be more specific: For any logical formula $\Phi$ of height at most $n$, rank$(\Phi) = $Height$(\Phi) $.

Now your SC2 step should not be $\Phi\circ \Phi$, as this is not a general formula of height $n+1$, but rather $\Phi\circ\Psi$. As the height of $\Phi\circ\Psi$ equals to $n+1$ the height of one of $\Phi$ or $\Psi$ needs to be $n$ and the other can have height at most n. Thus $1+\max(rank(\Phi),rank(\Psi)) = 1+n$ according to the induction hypothesis.

Note that we assumed in the induction hypothesis that the rank function return the height since we want $rank(\Phi)$ and $rank(\Psi)$ to both return values which are less than or equal to $n$ (and for one of them this should equal to $n$). If we do not do this the proof would not be complete since we have not proved what happen if the height of, say $\Phi$, is less than $n$.

So in general your proof is correct just a few details which should be improved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.